# CSS files are being sent with Content-Type: text/plain

Tags: css, go, server

I have looked around and haven't found anything specific for what I am after. I am building an API using Go's standard library. When serving up my resource files, my CSS files are sent as `text/plain` when I am wanting to send it as `text/css`.

The console throws an info message at me saying:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:3000/css/app.css".`

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    templates := populateTemplates()

    http.HandleFunc("/",
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
            requestedFile := req.URL.Path[1:]
            template := templates.Lookup(requestedFile + ".html")

            if template != nil {
                template.Execute(w, nil)
            } else {
                w.WriteHeader(404)
            }
        })

    http.HandleFunc("/img/", serveResource)
    http.HandleFunc("/css/", serveResource)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil))
}

func serveResource(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    path := "public" + req.URL.Path
    var contentType string
    if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".css") {
        contentType = "text/css"
    } else if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".png") {
        contentType = "image/png"
    } else {
        contentType = "text/plain"
    }

    f, err := os.Open(path)

    if err == nil {
        defer f.Close()
        w.Header().Add("Content Type", contentType)

        br := bufio.NewReader(f)
        br.WriteTo(w)
    } else {
        w.WriteHeader(404)
    }
}

func populateTemplates() *template.Template {
    result := template.New("templates")

    basePath := "templates"
    templateFolder, _ := os.Open(basePath)
    defer templateFolder.Close()

    templatePathRaw, _ := templateFolder.Readdir(-1)

    templatePaths := new([]string)
    for _, pathInfo := range templatePathRaw {
        if !pathInfo.IsDir() {
            *templatePaths = append(*templatePaths,
                basePath+"/"+pathInfo.Name())
        }
    }

    result.ParseFiles(*templatePaths...)

    return result
}
```

I believe I am sending it as `text/css`. Am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: @Karrot Kake answered your question. Also, consider [http.FileServer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer), it detects the content type.

Comment: I bet this is a pluralsight tuturial. I've been struggling with this error for 20mins now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The application is missing a "-" in the content type header name. Change the code to:

```
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", contentType)
```